# how to incorporate two types in one loop in python

Tags: python, append, tuples

If `subdivision(coordinate)` is a division code using bounding box theory, giving two outcomes - `subdivisionR, subdivisionL`;

```
A = array([[ 10., 110.],[200.,  90.],[210.,   0.], [-10.,  10.],[ 10., 110.]])
subdivision(A) = array([[ 10., 110.],[110.0, 99.47],[110.0, 4.54],[-10., 10.],[ 10., 110.]]), 
                 array([[110.0, 99.47],[200.,90.],[210., 0.],[110.0, 4.54],[110.0, 99.47]])
area(A) = 19550.0
```

[subdivision(A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b63MI.png)

Since I want to repeat `subdivision()` for all subdivided polygons until each area reaches near 200, I made below code. However, tuple index for `area()` is a single integer and tuple index for `subdivision()` is array of coordinates. If I want to append all subdivided polygons until each area reaches 200 in a list of coordinates, how can I fix the code below?

```
n=1
t=0
r=0
k=A

while area(subdivision(k)[n-1])>200:
    for i in range(t,n):
        np.append(k[0],subdivision(k)[0])[i]
        np.append(k[1],subdivision(k)[1])[i]
    t=2**r
    r=r+1
    n=2**r
```

Comment: Please don't do `2**` repeatedly. New `t` is old `n`. New `n` is always `t*2`.

Comment: Also, save `subdivision(k)`'s result. Then just append in a loop. Is that what you want?

Comment: every `subdivision(k)` gives me 2 outcomes. And I'm trying to repeat subdivision on `subdivision(k)[0]` and `subdivision(k)[1]`, which will give me 4 outcomes. nth loop creates 2**n result. That's why 2** is needed. Say for example, the list will look like `k`, `subdivision(k)[0]`, `subdivision(k)[1]`, `subdivision(subdivision(k)[0])[0]`, `subdivision(subdivision(k)[0])[1]`, `subdivision(subdivision(k)[1])[0]`, `subdivision(subdivision(k)[1])[1]` and so on.

Comment: Because I want to save all subdivision result until the area reaches 200, I've appended `subdivision(k)` in loop, but it won't work since `area()`'s type is numpy.float64 and `subdivision(k)`'s type is tuple.